# Ajax form in plugin admin page is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms, onsubmit

I am making a wordpress plugin on localhost. I add an ajax form in the custum admin panel for plugin. But the form not working. When I press on the submit button ("add" button) in my form, it shows an empty page and the address of the page changes to

> `http://localhost/wp-admin/admin.php?eventname=myevent&Event+Date=2014-12-11`

I searched alot about this on internet but I found no solution that can solve this problem. I think the problem is that jquery function is not linking with the submit button of the form.

My plugin code is:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Eventism
Plugin URI:
Description: Event Management System
Version: 1.0
Author: Ali Azlan
Author URI:
License: GPLv2 or later
*/

defined('ABSPATH') or die("No script kiddies please!");

//Include Javascript library
wp_enqueue_script('eventism', plugins_url( '/script1.js' , __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ));
// including ajax script in the plugin Myajax.ajaxurl
wp_localize_script( 'eventism', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));

wp_register_script( "eventism", plugins_url( '/script1.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

function eventism_activation() {
eventism_install();
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'eventism_activation');

function eventism_deactivation() {
}
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'eventism_deactivation');

function eventism_install () {
global $wpdb;

/*
* We'll set the default character set and collation for this table.
* If we don't do this, some characters could end up being converted
* to just ?'s when saved in our table.
*/

$charset_collate = '';

if ( ! empty( $wpdb->charset ) ) {
$charset_collate = "DEFAULT CHARACTER SET {$wpdb->charset}";
}

if ( ! empty( $wpdb->collate ) ) {
$charset_collate .= " COLLATE {$wpdb->collate}";
}

$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE eventism_users (
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
cell varchar(13) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
eventcode varchar(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
cnic varchar(13) DEFAULT '',
email varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
confirm VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT 'n' NOT NULL,
time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE KEY id (id),
UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (id ASC)
) $charset_collate;";

$sql2 = "CREATE TABLE eventism_events (
id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
event varchar(10) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
event_date varchar(30) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
create_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE KEY id (id),
UNIQUE INDEX id_UNIQUE (id ASC)
) $charset_collate;";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql1 );
dbDelta( $sql2 );

$wpdb->insert(
$table_name='eventism_events',
array(
'event' => 'swaik1',
'event_date' => '10 december 2014',
)
);

}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'eventism_menu' );

function eventism_menu() {
add_menu_page( 'Eventism', 'Eventism', 'manage_options', 'eventism_menu');
add_submenu_page( 'eventism_menu', 'Eventism', 'Eventism', 'manage_options', 'eventism_menu', 'eventism_options_events' );
}

function eventism_options_events() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}
echo '<div class="wrap">';
echo '<h1><b>Eventism</b></h1><sub><i> by Azlan</i><hr>
';

echo '<h1>Add new Event</h1>';

echo '
<form type="post" id="newevent" action="">
<b>Event Name: </b>
<input type="text" name="eventname" id="eventname">
<b>Event Date: </b>
<input type="date" name="Event Date" id="eventdate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="add1">
</form>

<div id="feedback"></div><hr>
';
echo '
<h1>Customer Database</h1>

';
}

function addevent(){

global $wpdb;

$name = $_POST['eventname'];
// $date = $_POST['eventdate'];
$date = "meridate";

if($wpdb->insert('eventism_events',array(
'event'=>$name,
'event_date'=>$date,
))==FALSE){

echo "Error";

}
else {
echo "Event Added Successfully!";

}
die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_addevent', 'addevent');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_addevent', 'addevent');

?>
```

And my jquery file (script1.js) code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#add1").click(function(){
var eventname = jQuery("#eventname").val();
var eventdate = jQuery("#eventdate").val();
jQuery.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
data: {"action": "addevent", "eventname":eventname},
success: function(data){
alert(data);
}
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the address also changed on click, this mean the page reload before and ajax event. So you need to Prevent the default submit event with `event.preventDefault()`

```
jQuery("#add1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var eventname = jQuery("#eventname").val();
    var eventdate = jQuery("#eventdate").val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "addevent", "eventname":eventname, eventdate:eventdate},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I tested this and @jogesh_pi is correct. It's only the `event.preventDefault()` that is missing

Comment: sir I have another problem.. in jquery code, I just have "eventname" in the data. What should I have to do to add "eventdate" to it.

Comment: Hi ali, in your code you have to send event date like eventname, and you have to uncomment the $_POST[eventdate] from php code that's it.

Comment: yes I will uncomment the $_POST[eventdate] from the php code. But I dont know how to add eventdate like eventname in jquery... I have to add another function in jquery for eventdate or I can pass two variables to the data parameter..?